# How to upgrade from using deprecated SecDigestGetData method?

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain, private-key

At some point, it seems that Apple has removed the `SecDigestGetData` method from the Security framework. I'm trying to upgrade some old code that compares a certificate digest to see if we've found the right one. The original code looks like this:

```
uint8 candidate_sha1_hash[20];
CSSM_DATA digest;
digest.Length = sizeof(candidate_sha1_hash);
digest.Data = candidate_sha1_hash;
if ((SecDigestGetData(CSSM_ALGID_SHA1, &digest, &certData) == CSSM_OK) &&
  (hashData.Length == digest.Length) &&
  (!memcmp(hashData.Data, digest.Data, digest.Length))) {
  found = TRUE;
  break;
}
```

I get this error when it is compiled:

```
export_private_key.c:103:10: error: implicit declaration of function 'SecDigestGetData' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if ((SecDigestGetData(CSSM_ALGID_SHA1, &digest, &certData) == CSSM_OK) &&
         ^
```

How can I upgrade this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the fingerprint yourself by extracting the DER data and hashing it. In C it would look like this.

```c
#include <Security/SecCertificate.h>
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

CFDataRef _Nonnull digest_from_certificate(SecCertificateRef _Nonnull certificate) {
    const CFDataRef certificateData = SecCertificateCopyData(certificate);
    uint8 digest [CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA1(CFDataGetBytePtr(certificateData), (CC_LONG) CFDataGetLength(certificateData), digest);
    return CFDataCreate(NULL, digest, CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH);
}
```

In Swift the implementation would look like this.

```swift
// Extracting the DER data.
let certificate: SecCertificate = ...
let certificateData = SecCertificateCopyData(certificate) as Data
```

Hashing can be done with `CommonCrypto` or, since iOS 13, with `CryptoKit`.

```swift
import CommonCrypto

let certificateBytes = Array(certificateData)
var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
_ = CC_SHA1(certificateBytes, CC_LONG(certificateBytes.count), &digest)

print(Data(digest) as NSData)
```

```swift
import CryptoKit

Insecure.SHA1.hash(data: SecCertificateCopyData(certificate) as Data)
```

An alternative approach would be to use `SecCertificateCopyValues`.

```swift
if let values = SecCertificateCopyValues(certificate, ["Fingerprints"] as CFArray, &error) as? [String: Any] {
    if let fingerprints = (values["Fingerprints"] as? [CFString: Any])?[kSecPropertyKeyValue] as? [[CFString: Any]] {
        if let sha1 = fingerprints.first(where: { ($0[kSecPropertyKeyLabel] as? String) == "SHA-1" }).map({ $0[kSecPropertyKeyValue] as? Data }) {
            print(sha1 as NSData)
        }
    }
}
```

`SecCertificateCopyValues` returns a dictionary described by certificate property keys. The value of such dictionary can be another dictionary or an array of dictionaries. Now, as far as I know, certificates should have SHA-256 as a minimum (SHA-1 is merely used for backwards compatibility), meaning you'll likely get an array of fingerprints, hence my example.

Comment: The language is C

Comment: @Andrew I've added the C implementation